# Pro regex converting these impossible-to-regex examples?

Tags: php, regex, serialization, data-conversion, recursive-regex

**Example of input**

```
vulture (wing)
tabulations: one leg; two legs; flying
father; master; patriarch    
mat (box)
pedistal; blockade; pilar
animal belly (oval)
old style: naval
jackal's belly; jester    slope of hill (arch)
key; visible; enlightened
```

Basically, I'm having trouble with some more complicated regex commands.  Most of the code I'm finding that uses regex is very simple, but I could use it in so many places if I could get good with it.  Would you look at the kind of stuff I'm trying to do and see if you can convert any of it?

1. Arrayize the word or words between the braces, "(" and ")".
2. Arrayize the first words following a new line ending xor four spaces and then a closing brace, ")", and a space and an open brace " (" AND the first words in the document up until a space and an open brace " (".
3. On any line with semicolons, arrayize the words which are separated by semicolons.  Get the word or words after the last semicolon but do not get the words after a line break or four consecutive spaces.  Words from lines that begin with the string "tabulations:" should not be included in this array, even though lines that begin with the string "tabulations:" have semicolons on them.  If a new line ending in a close brace, ")" comes before a line containing semicolons and not starting with "tabulations" "no alternates" to the array, instead.
4. Get the word or words following the colon and preceding the line break on a line that begins with the string "old style:".  If a new line ending in a close brace, ")" comes before a "tabulations:"-starting line, add "no old style" to the array, instead.
5. The same as 3, except only for lines that begin with the string "tabulations:".  If a new line ending in a close brace, ")" comes before a "tabulations:"-starting line, add "no tabulations" to the array, instead.

I am trying to figure out how to do this via PHP, but I would be happy if anyone could field these requests in any language, especially php, C++, javascript, or batch.  I also know that these are all very difficult to show, even for a puzzle lover.  So, I promise 100 bonus points as soon as bounties are available for any complete answer.

-Edit-

**First solution I was working on**

Okay, so the first solution I was working on is to solve 3.  I tried breaking the lines at the semicolons, and I was then hoping to grab the data, line-by-line and edit it further.

```
$input = file_get_contents('explode.txt');
foreach(explode("\n", $input) as $line){
  $words = explode(';', $line); 
  foreach($words as $word){
  echo $word;
  }
}
```

Basically, looking at the output, the data ended up in the same format it was already in, only subtract the semicolons.  This wasn't very useful, and I decided to stop.

**Second solution I am working on**

This is based around this line of code: `preg_match_all('/\;([^;]+)\}/', $myFile, $matches)`.

There's now a working solution to part 1 of the question, [thanks to EPB and fge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675385/recursive-regex-with-garbled-text-surrounding-getting-arrayarray):

```
$myFile = file_get_contents('fakexample.txt');
function get_between($startString, $endString, $myFile){
  //Escape start and end strings.
  $startStringSafe = preg_quote($startString, '/');
  $endStringSafe = preg_quote($endString, '/');
  //non-greedy match any character between start and end strings. 
  //s modifier should make it also match newlines.
  preg_match_all("/$startStringSafe(.*?)$endStringSafe/s", $myFile, $matches);
  return $matches;
}
$list = get_between("(", ")", $myFile);
foreach($list[1] as $list){
  echo $list."\n";
}
```

Some issues I had were that I wasn't using RegEx correctly.  I think the `ArrayArray` return problem was because I didn't encapsulate the preg_match_all function such that it returned $matches to a private function.  I'm still unsure.  I'm also still unsure about whether I should be using the `file_get_contents()` function to read the file.

**The third solution attempt**

So, I had an initial idea of how I wanted to approach this, and I decided to go about it my own way.  Again, I started with question 1 because it seemed easiest.  It has the fewest exceptions

```
function find_between($input,$start,$end) {
  if (strpos($input,$start) === false || strpos($input,$end) === false) {
    return false;
  } else {
    $start_position = strpos($input,$start)+strlen($start);
    $end_position = strpos($input,$end);
    return substr($input,$start_position,$end_position-$start_position);
  }
}

$myFile = file_get_contents('explode.txt');

$output = find_between($myFile,'(',')');

echo $output;
```

As far as I can tell, this will work.  The issue I'm having is with the recursion.  I tried `foreach($output as $output){echo $output;}`, but this gave me an error.  It seems obvious to me that it's because I haven't recursed and so haven't arrayized.  The reason I stopped along this path is because I was told by several programmers that I was doomed to failure.  So, I'm currently back to working on solution 2.

Comment: You should show initiative and show us what you have so far. We will not do the coding for you.

Comment: @Howard, I have a variety of different kinds of solutions but none of them are complete.  If you'd like to see some of that?  I'm not sure what the best way to begin to approach this is (not even sure if I should use regex).  I don't want to give people the wrong idea.

Comment: +1, see how far you get and let us know when you're running into a problem you can't figure out yourself. It's the best learning experience.

Comment: @Rijk okay...  I'll give you some of the stuff I'm working with, right now.  Thank you.

Comment: @Rijk Thank you, again.  I added the lines of reasoning I've followed so far in my code.  I'm going to continue working on solution two.  If you are really good at this stuff, could you at least tell me which, if any, of these three paths is best for me to continue down?

Comment: @Howard Any other advise?  I want to try to get the question re-opened.  I'll try to post more complete code, but I'm still hoping someone will give me a push in the right direction to help me move towards getting it reopened.

Comment: I can't understand the close reason.  Is it only incomplete, or is it vague also?  Is it impossible to answer?  There's no useful info at all.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Note that most of the close votes very done before you edited your question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Howard Thanks, bro.  I really appreciate your bid in it.  I'm going to separate the questions and go as far as I can, step-by-step, because I think the problem is that I'm overwhelming people with such a huge leap.  People have been really cool with me so far, and I was surprised until I thought about it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Is this for a homework assignment? These instructions(1-5) are not making any sense to me, as far as when you would have reason to do any of them outside an academic pursuit. It also seems like you're new to not only regexes but also PHP in general. As @Howard pointed out, we will not do your work for you.

Apart from that, if you need help w/regex, I'd be more than happy to assist; however it doesn't appear that that's what you need help with the most.

So here is what I can offer you, with regards to your question:

3) "On any line with semicolons, array-ize the words which are separated by semicolons.
Get the word or words after the last semicolon but do not get the words after a line break or four consecutive spaces. -> Easy: Explode by newline (\n)
Words from lines that begin with the string "tabulations:" should not be included in this array, even though lines that begin with the string "tabulations:" have semicolons on them. -> This is a bit trickier. First, regex for semicolon but NOT colon. This will most likely have to be handled by two separate regexes: first "tabulations:" and if that's NOT found, then search for semicolons. If this regex succeeds, then you can explode by semicolon and now you've got all the data to make all your arrays.
If a new line ending in a close brace, ")" comes before a line containing semicolons and not starting with "tabulations" "no alternates" to the array, instead." -> This one I'm leaving up to you to figure out, for more than a few reasons. ;-)

Comment: You should put all that chatty stuff in comments (or out the window).  Because people won't rate your answer well if you use a lot of meta language.

I've used all these in the field.  I was new to regex when I wrote these questions up, but I was struggling to compose them.  I used an off-site forum to get the answer because the answers here didn't come.  I had a specific use for each expression planned prior to writing the question out.