# Recursive regex with garbled text surrounding? Getting "ArrayArray"

Tags: php, regex, serialization, recursive-regex

I asked a similar question, but it was closed for being too broad.  Basically, I have a bunch of questions like this.  I'm hoping just asking one will be easier.  I've tried some different ways to solve this, but none of them actually work.

I have a text file with a lot of data.  The only data that I'm interested in falls between two brackets, "(" ")".  I'm wondering how to get each instance of info that lies between brackets into an array.

The code I'm using right now returns `ArrayArray`:

```
function get_between($startString, $endString, $myFile){
  preg_match_all('/\$startString([^$endString]+)\}/', $myFile, $matches);
  return $matches;
}
$myFile = file_get_contents('explode.txt');
$list = get_between("&nbsp(", ")", $myFile);
foreach($list as $list){
  echo $list;
}
```

Comment: Use var_dump() or print_r() to see the content. There are quite a few mistakes in this code, starting with the regex. ArrayArray is simply the result of outputing arrays with echo.

Comment: You say you want to capture text between brackets, then what are `$startstring` and `$endstring` in your example? What's more, as @Louis-PhilippeHuberdeau says, your regex is wrong anyway. Please expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function get_between($startString, $endString, $myFile){
  //Escape start and end strings.
  $startStringSafe = preg_quote($startString, '/');
  $endStringSafe = preg_quote($endString, '/');
  //non-greedy match any character between start and end strings. 
  //s modifier should make it also match newlines.
  preg_match_all("/$startStringSafe(.*?)$endStringSafe/s", $myFile, $matches);
  return $matches;
}
$myFile = 'fkdhkvdf(mat(((ch1)vdsf b(match2) dhdughfdgs (match3)';
$list = get_between("(", ")", $myFile);
foreach($list[1] as $list){
  echo $list."\n";
}
```

I did this and it seems to work.  (Obviously, you'll need to replace my $myFile assignment line with your file_get_contents statement.)  A few things:

A: Variable replacement won't occur with single-quotes.  So your preg_replace_all regular expression won't work as a result.  As it literally adds $startString to your expression instead of (. (I also removed the check for } at the end of the matched string.  Add it back in if you need it with `\\}` just before the ending delimiter.)

B: $list will be an array of arrays.  I believe by default, index zero will contain all full matches.  index one will contain the first subpattern match.

C: This only works so long as $endString will not ever be found inside of a subpattern you are attempting to match.  Say, if you expect (matc(fF)) to give you matc(fF), it won't.  It'll give you match(fF.  You'll need a more powerful parser if you want to get the former result in this case.

Edit: The get_between function here should work with `&nbsp;(` and `)}` as well, or whatever else you'd want.

Comment: This is the most complete answer and it works.  May I also ask about this: I'm using file_get_contents to populate the `$myFile` variable.  Is that unsafe?  Should I be using `fopen()` and `fread()`?

Comment: Actually, that's a pretty good question.  (Hence the comment upvote.) `file_get_contents` is preferred if you are reading the entire file into a string in memory as it allows PHP to use memory mapping techniques to improve performance. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: An issue that I had in my next question, which pitted regex against line breaks, was that I wasn't sure whether `file_get_contents` put the string onto one line, or if it somehow mapped the line breaks.  It seems it puts it all on one line, by the output of a `get_between("^", "whatever")`.

Comment: `file_get_contents` loads a string with line breaks, but it doesn't do anything else with them.  The line breaks are there, but sometimes you need to do something extra to see depending on how you're displaying them. For example, if you are viewing the result content on an HTML page, you can run output through `nl2br` to make the content have breaks when viewed in the browser.  (It adds `<br>` tags at newlines to tell the browser to break.) Also, when viewed in the browser, my echo loop could use: `echo nl2br("$list\n");` Another option: Wrap the output in `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is completely misleaded.

First: `[^...]` is a complemented character class. A complemented character class is an atom, and whatever `...` is is the set of characters which must *not* be allowed at this point. Ie, `[^ab]` will allow anything but `a` and `b`.

Second: you seem to want to be able to capture between parens. But a paren (open or closing) is a special character in a regex. So, in your example, if `$startString` is `&nbsp(`, the paren will be interpreted as a regex metacharacter.

Third: unfortunately, this cannot be solved with regexes, but nested `$startString` and `$endString` cannot be matched (well, they can with perl, but perl is perl).

The closest you can get to what you really want is rewriting your regex to use with `preg_match_all` as follows:

```
$start = preg_quote($startString, '/');
$end = preg_quote($endString, '/');
$re = '/\Q' . $start . '\E'       # literal $start
    . '('                         # capture...
    . '(?:(?!\Q' . $end . '\E).)' # any character, as long as $end is not found at this position,
    . '+)'                        # one or more times
    . '\Q' . $end . '\E/';        # literal $end
```

and then use that as your first argument to `preg_match_all`.

The `\Q` and `\E` regex modifiers tell that anything between the first and second should be treated as literals -- hence the paren in `&nbsp(` will be treated literally, and not as the group opening metacharacter.

Comment: So the string is basically `\Q(\E((?:(?!\Q)\E).)+)\Q)\E` after I apply ( and ) to `$start` and `$end`, right?  I get the 'delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash' error.  So I added `'/'. ... . '/'` to `$re`, and then I echoed `$match` and tried `foreach($match as $match){echo $match;}` and had the same problem.  I got `Array` and then `ArrayArray`. :'(

Comment: Ah, yeah :/ I keep forgetting about this, PHP needs its regexes surrounded by a delimiter. Add a '/' before the first '\Q' and after the final `\E`, and use `preg_quote` as shown in the other answer to escape / in your start and end strings

Comment: fge, do you forget because you're used to PCRE?

Comment: No, I forget because I don't do PHP ;)

Comment: I tried this code in various different ways, and I had trouble outputting the result.  So, I can see how the answer is correct.  Thank you for your help, fge.

Comment: This is as far as I could go on my own: http://pastebin.com/BSU0SEqw.  I think that I need to encase the `preg_match_all()` function into a function so that I can get a return on $matches, otherwise it won't work?  I'm very new at PHP, though.  Thanks, again.